# Open imgcache.0 file programmatically

Tags: android, thumbnails, data-recovery

I would like to know if someone here could help me to `'open'` `imgcache.0 file` located in `Android\data\com.android.gallery3d` folder `programmatically.` This is like a thumb file containing miniatures of old pictures, am I right?

How can I open it?